# How do I draw a DensityPlot in polar coordinates?

Tags: graphics, plotting

I am trying to plot $J_m(\chi_{mn} r) \cos(m\phi),$ where $J_m(\chi_{mn}) =0,$ as a `DensityPlot` in polar coordinates (solution to 2D wave equation in polar coordinates). First, some definitions

```
besselzero = N@Table[BesselJZero[l, n], {l, 0, 25}, {n, 1, 25}];
bzeros[l_, n_] := besselzero[[l + 1, n]];
```

for speed purposes.

For the purposes of this question consider $m=3$ (but there's essentially the same problem for any $m$):

```
DensityPlot[
 Cos[3 ArcTan[y/x] ] BesselJ[3, bzeros[3,1]Sqrt[x^2+y^2]],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},
 Epilog->{Thick,Circle[]},PlotRange->{-1,1},
 RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},Norm[{x,y}]<1.]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is *nearly* right, except that the sign on the left-hand side ($y<0$) of the plot is wrong (it should not be mirror symmetric around $y=0$, rather continue alternating positive and negative after each $\Delta\phi=\pi/3$).

Looking at the `Plot3D` of `ArcTan[y/x]` I realized the cause of the problem was because of how `ArcTan` is defined, so I tried a workaround:

```
DensityPlot[
 Cos[3 Piecewise[{{0, x > 0 && y == 0}, {π/2, 
       x == 0 && y > 0}, {(3 π)/2, x == 0 && y < 0}, {(2 π)/2,
        x < 0 && y == 0}, {ArcTan[y/x], 
       x > 0 && y > 0}, {ArcTan[y/x] + π, 
       x < 0 && y > 0}, {ArcTan[y/x] + π, 
       x < 0 && y < 0}, {ArcTan[y/x] + 2 π, 
       x > 0 && y < 0}}] ] BesselJ[3, 
   bzeros[3, 1] Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 Epilog -> {Thick, Circle[]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y}] < 1.]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is *nearly* right, except for those white regions. Is there a better way to plot functions of this sort?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the two-argument form [`ArcTan[x, y]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArcTan.html) instead of `ArcTan[y/x]`:

> `ArcTan[x,y]` gives the arc tangent of y/x, taking into account which quadrant the point $(x,y)$ is in.

It just works:

[image]

Comment: Yeesh. It's that simple.

Answer (score 16):

Quickly, now, which values are positive and which are negative?

Even when a legend may be present, it can help to have additional visual cues concerning the values in a density plot.  `ReliefPlot` will do this with a "hillshading" algorithm.  It also reverses the default colors, because it is more natural to think of light colors as being high or closer to the viewer.

To overcome the technical computing problems, isolate the calculations of the arctangent and the Bessel function:

```
ClearAll[arctan, besselj];
arctan[0., 0.] = 0;
arctan[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];
besselj[m_, \[Chi]_, x_] /; x > 1 := 0;
besselj[m_, \[Chi]_, x_] := BesselJ[m, \[Chi] x];
```

This takes care of the special case at the origin and expedites the calculations beyond the unit circle (which are not wanted).

Because `ReliefPlot` does not appear to have the analog of `RegionFunction`, a reasonable workaround is to mask the undesired areas:

```
mask = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> White, BoundaryStyle -> None];
```

Finally, we need to remember that `ReliefPlot` builds the image from the *bottom* to the *top*.  To generate its array, then, we need to go in *reverse* order of the first coordinate.  Whence the work is done as

```
Block[{m = 3, n = 1, \[Chi], data},
 \[Chi] = BesselJZero[m, n];
 data = ParallelTable[ 
   besselj[m, \[Chi], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Cos[m arctan[x, y]], 
   {x, 1, -1, -.01}, {y, -1, 1, .01}];
 Show[
  ReliefPlot[data, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   Axes -> {True, True}, AxesOrigin -> {-1.05, -1.05}, Frame -> False],
  mask
  ]
 ]
```

[image: BesselJ]

The improvements are subtle but helpful: it is now visually clear where the peaks and valleys are located.  If the effect is not strong enough, exaggerate it by lowering the second `LightingAngle` value (the help page shows how).

Comment: I typically include a legend for the plot, but this is a very nice approach. I also like your approach to dealing with the plot range by defining the Bessel function differently. Other than dealing with the {0,0} coordinate, what is the benefit to using the arctan definition?

Comment: Is there a functional (not array-based) version of `ReliefPlot`?

Comment: @Eli: (1) Because `ReliefPlot` insists on working with an array of machine reals, even a single `Indeterminate` result throws it off.  You are right; the purpose of separately defining `arctan` was to cope with that problem at $\{0,0\}$.  (2) Yes: make a 3D (surface) plot and set the viewpoint from (essentially) infinitely far above the surface.  This might actually be a more efficient solution (but it's a little fussier in terms of needing to set many more graphing parameters: get rid of the mesh, set the viewpoint and lighting, etc.).

Answer (score 11):

As to the white lines:

Those are caused by small gaps in the plot introduced by the `Exclusions` option, which is trying to avoid jumps caused by discontinuities in your function.  (In this case it's because your function uses `Piecewise`)

You can turn them off if necessary by using `Exclusions -> None`:

```
DensityPlot[
 Cos[3 Piecewise[{
          {0, x > 0 && y == 0}, 
          {Pi/2, x == 0 && y > 0}, 
          {(3 Pi)/2, x == 0 && y < 0}, 
          {(2 Pi)/2, x < 0 && y == 0},        
          {ArcTan[y/x], x > 0 && y > 0}, 
          {ArcTan[y/x] + Pi, x < 0 && y > 0}, 
          {ArcTan[y/x] + Pi, x < 0 && y < 0}, 
          {ArcTan[y/x] + 2 Pi, x > 0 && y < 0}
         }]] BesselJ[3, bzeros[3, 1] Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], 
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Circle[]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y}] < 1.], 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The difficulties with either single-argument `Arctan[y/x]` or two-argument `ArcTan[x,y]` (the latter being undefined at the origin, as was addressed by @whuber) were also discussed on [MathGroup](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/A8Lwk6O7P58/-KpM39BJWUkJ). Heike's suggestion there was to use `Arg[x + I y]` to get the polar angle. But in fact it turns out to be slightly more efficient (and perhaps more readable) to use the function `CoordinatesFromCartesian` in the `VectorAnalysis` package:

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]

SetCoordinates[Cylindrical];

DensityPlot[
 Apply[Cos[3 #2] BesselJ[3, bzeros[3, 1] #1] &, 
  CoordinatesFromCartesian[{x, y, 0}]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Circle[]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Norm[{x, y}] < 1.]]
```

(there was an unnecessary `z` argument in the `RegionFunction` of your example)

One final remark, related to your setup with `BesselJZeros`: instead of preparing them in a table, you may want to use the fact that `BesselJZeros` threads over lists! That makes the initial calculation faster than with a table. Of course you only do that loop once in this application, but I thought it's worth pointing out for the benefit of more complex applications.

Comment: I'm not sure that preparing the zeros in a table is any slower, since I only evaluate numerically at the end.

Comment: @Eli That's probably true. I just wanted to mention it because I've found it to be very useful for my own purposes... Similarly, when doing plots involving large sums of BesselJ I found it faster to use the listability of BesselJ by going to ListDensityPlot instead of DensityPlot. But those things don't matter much in your example.

Answer (score 5):

- Set `DisplayFunction ->  ReplaceAll[{r_Real, t_Real} :> {r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}]`, the same way as  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/300018/72111

```
m = 3; (* m=4 *)
f[r_, θ_] := Cos[m*θ]*BesselJ[m, BesselJZero[m, 1]  r];
DensityPlot[
 f[r, θ] // Evaluate, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2  π}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{r_Real, t_Real} :> {r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}], 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
 PlotLabel -> Style[StringJoin["m=", ToString@m], Bold, 20, Blue]]
```

[image]