# Polar Plot of a two variable function

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a polar plot of a two variable function, which has a radial and an  angular part. For instance `Y[r,φ]=r^2 Cos[φ]`.

I can make this plot using `ContourPlot`, but is there a way to do it using `PolarPLot`?
My `ContourPlot` is

```
Y[r_, f_] := r^2 Cos[f]
ContourPlot[Y[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, 0, 1}(*Radius till 1*), {y, 0, 60}(*Angle from 0 to 60*)]
```

[image]

Comment: The argument of `Cos`, `ArcTan` etc. is assumed to be in radians, multiply by `Degree` to convert from degrees.

Comment: Well, the help on `PolarPlot[]` states _"Use ContourPlot and RegionPlot for implicit curves and regions:"_

Comment: @VLC:Thank's for that! I didn't know it!!!

Comment: @belisarius: I've seen, but I would like to plot this two variable function in the most efficient way...and I am not sure on how to do it without polar plot...

Comment: Well, I just posted an answer :)

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3680)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PolarPlot[]` is a handicapped plotting function (it doesn't support `Filling`, for example). Much easier with other functions:

```
h[r_, f_] := r^2 Cos[f]
Quiet@Show[
        ContourPlot[h[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
                  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, f}, 0 < ArcTan[x, y] < Pi/3 && x^2 + y^2 < 1],
                  Contours -> 10,  AspectRatio -> 1], 
         Graphics@Circle[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another possibility:

```
Plot3D[h[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]],
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -1, 1},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 Mesh -> 7,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.8]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may even draw your Pi/3 angle on the surface:

```
Plot3D[h[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]],
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -1, 1},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
 MeshFunctions -> {UnitBox@(ArcTan[#2, #1] - Pi/3) &},
 Mesh -> 7,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.8]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I believe the first plot should be fine!!! Thank you!