# Bessel functions and ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I'm trying to plot some eigenfunctions (for a semicircle) in *Mathematica*. Functions are of the following form:
$$g_{ms}=J_{2m+1}(y_{ms}x) \sin ((2m+1)\varphi)$$
For example, for $m=0$ and $s=1$ it should look like what I drew by hand in the attached picture - something semicircular (sorry for bad drawing):
[image: r]

Well, I don't have much experience with *Mathematica* and the "code" I wrote so far doesn't give me the right result.
Here's my try:

```
m = 0;
s = 1;

dat = 
  Table[
    {x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}], y = RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
     BesselJ[(2*m + 1), BesselJZero[m, s]*x]* Sin[(2*m + 1)*ArcTan[x, y]]}, 
    {1000}];

ListContourPlot[dat]
```

The plot I get is like this (see below). What am I doing wrong?

[image: 2]

This is what I should get:

[image]

Edit: Thank you all. Now I use this code:

```
m = 1;
s = 1;
z = 2 m + 1;
ContourPlot[
BesselJ[z, BesselJZero[m, s]*Norm[{x, y}]]*
Sin[z*ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Contours -> 10]
```

And I've got this plot:
[image]

Just another question - The repeating pattern doesn't end at x=1, as it does in the image from instructions. Did I mess something up with the code or do I just have to normalize it somehow?

Comment: Hi ! You should go to the help centre read how to properly format your code and edit your question to reflect those guidelines.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to format it properly. In the meantime, I still need an answer to my problem.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the eigenfunction formula you have?

Comment: My thinking is your hand plot is wrong, or I don't follow what it is you are plotting.  The expression is zero for x=0, so you must get a zero contour line straight up the middle..

Comment: Now that you said it, I see that the formula I have is zero at x=0. However, in the instructions for this task (the whole task is actually about a method for solving PDEs) it is included that this formula returns solutions like the file I just attached (see edited post). First column has s=1, second column has s=2, first row has m=0, second m=1 and third m=2. I admit I'm completely lost now. I'll reread everything I have on this assignment. However, if you have any ideas about how to get these plots, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: may be more a math.stackexchange.com question..

Comment: Your formula should have the radial coordinate $r$ where $x$ appears in the Bessel function. I'm voting to close because this is not a *Mathematica*-related problem.

Comment: For your edited question, you may want to have a look at [How do I draw a DensityPlot in polar coordinates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3680/245)

Comment: Jens, thank you for the link. I read it all and tried everything others mentioned in comments. But the plot is still too big. I can crop it using RegionFunction, but it doesn't give me the right solution.