# How to make a plot over a domain

Tags: plotting, image3d, slider2d

Say I have a function $y=x^2 + 2x + 1$ and I want to plot it over the cross sectional area of a hollow cylinder between $x=1$ and $x=2$ in Mathematica. See the attached example below. How do you go about making figures of this type in Mathematica? [image]

Comment: We need three variables to  plot such figure, not only two variables.

Comment: $\theta \in {0,\pi/2}$

Comment: What are the relation between `x,y` and `θ`?

Comment: Your "equation" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

- Maybe you want a `DensityPlot` in polar coordinates with function `f[r_, θ_] := r^2 + 2 r + 1;`.
- See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/300171/72111

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[r_, θ_] := r^2 + 2 r + 1;
DensityPlot[
 f[r, θ] // Evaluate, {r, 1, 2}, {θ, 0, π/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{r_Real, t_Real} :> {r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}], 
 ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your equation makes no sense.  But the closest thing that *does* make sense is:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[r^2 + 2 r + 1,
 {r, 1, 2},
 {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/2}.
 ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

[image]